# Checking of a basic python function

Tags: python

Can anyone check my code:

```
def mean(n):
    i, sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum = sum+i
    return (sum/n)

val = mean(4)
print(val)
```

I am a beginner at python. 
So can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Help you out of *what*?  What is the problem?

Comment: Please include a concrete question. Do you get an error? If so, please provide the backtracing of the error.
Hint: `i, sum` are two variables, `0` is *one* number. 
Optimally, avoid the variable name `sum` because it has special meaning in python and already is a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    i, sum = 0
```

gets you this error:

`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

because you're trying to assign two values from an `int`, which only has one value.  To fix this, you could do:

```
    i = 0
    sum = 0
```

or:

```
    i, sum = 0, 0
```

or better yet, just don't initialize `i` here, because it's going to be initialized inside your `for` loop and is not used outside of that loop.

```
def mean(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum = sum+i
    return (sum/n)
```

Comment: Even better: `return (sum(range(1,n+1))/n)`

Comment: I mean, we could also just `import mean from statistics` but I assume that's not the point.

Comment: That depends on just what "the point" is.

Comment: Thank you to all for helping me out.